# Create timed image slide show where each image is a link?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a timed image slide show where each image can made be made a clickable link. I have tried using css web animation but that doesn't work because each image is stacked on top of each other and only the transparency changes revealing different images and so they cant be clickable links.  Any thoughts or links to tutorials would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
m

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you were doing before, but after the opacity of the image fades out to 0, you will want to then set it to `display: none;` ... This will prevent the user from being able to click on it, allowing the click to pass through to the next image underneath.

I can't tell you much else without any code or examples of what you would like to happen, but hopefully that helps you out.